# The cosets of $\mathbb{nZ}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'd like to show that the only cosets of $\mathbb{nZ}$ are $\bar a$ for $a=0,1,\dots,n-1$ where $\bar a$ denotes the equivalence class containing $a$.

Proof. Any integer $x$ can be written as $x=ny+r$, $0\le r\lt n$. So $x\equiv r\text{ }(\text{mod } n)$. Thus the equivalence classes are of the form $\bar x$ where $x\lt n$. Next, we show that $a\neq b \implies \bar a \neq \bar b$ for all $a,b\lt n$. Suppose $a\neq b$. $a-b = nk+r$, $r=0\implies a=nk+b$ but $a,b \lt n$ so $a=b$ contradicting the assumption $a\neq b$

Is my proof ok?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: You should specify what $a$ and $b$ etc are. And why $\Bbb n\Bbb Z$ instead of $n\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @xavierm02 I did not get your question

Comment: You used a special font for the $n$ ($\Bbb n$), the same one as on $\Bbb Z$ but while on $Z$, it's here to make it stand out as a set (or something else? anyway, it's a convention), I had never seen it on the $n$ so I wondered why you used that font for the $n$ too.